# Call an array from one method to another method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have a method A in which I have created an array. Now I want to use the array in another method B and was wondering if there is any possibility that I can call the method A inside method B and use the array instead of creating the array in each and every method I create.

```
public static void myArray() {
    String[][] resultCard =  new String[][]{ 
                { " ", "A", "B", "C"},
                { "Maths", "78", "98","55"}, 
                { "Physics", "55", "65", "88"}, 
                { "Java", "73", "66", "69"},
             };
}

public static void A() {
    //Not sure how I can include the array (myArray) here   
}

public static void B() {
    //Not sure how I can include the array (myArray) here   
}
```

Comment: Show parts of code... That would explain in detail of what you are speaking about... Not only words, even code explains !!

Comment: [Pass it as an argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html).

Comment: Yes, used a instance variable (declare it outside of a method), or return it using a method.

Comment: Your title is slightly misleading (and sensless)...

Comment: Not sure what you mean but I'll give you an answer from what I THINK I understood.

Comment: Put it *outside* the method: `static String[][] resultCard = ...;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a text (comment) illustrated explanation (both the *question* and the *answer*):

```
public Object[] methodA() {
    // We are method A
    // In which we create an array
    Object[] someArrayCreatedInMethodA = new Object[10];
    // And we can returned someArrayCreatedInMethodA
    return someArrayCreatedInMethodA;
}

public void methodB() {
    // Here we are inside another method B
    // And we want to use the array
    // And there is a possibility that we can call the method A inside method B
    Object[] someArrayCreatedAndReturnedByMethodA = methodA();
    // And we have the array created in method A
    // And we can use it here (in method B)
    // Without creating it in method B again
}
```

**Edit:**

You edited your question and included your code. In your code the array is not created in method A but in the `myArray()`, and you don't return it, so it is "lost" after the `myArray()` method returns (if it is ever called).

Suggestion: declare your array as an attribute of your class, make it static, and you can simply refer to it as `resultCard` from both methods `a()` and `b()`:

```
private static String[][] resultCard = new String[][] {
    { " ", "A", "B", "C"},
    { "Maths", "78", "98","55"},
    { "Physics", "55", "65", "88"},
    { "Java", "73", "66", "69"},
};

public static void A() {
    // "Not sure how I can include the array (myArray) here"
    // You can access it and work with it simply by using its name:
    System.out.println(resultCard[3][0]); // Prints "Java"
    resultCard[3][0] = "Easy";
    System.out.println(resultCard[3][0]); // Prints "Easy"
}
```

Comment: hi Icza,
Thanks for the code but after implementing the code I am getting following errors:

Illegal modifier for parameter resultCard; only final is permitted on the first line where you have put private static String[][]... If I remove the words private static then the error is gone.

2nd error I am getting at void[] is an invalid type on public static void A() line...

Comment: Note: `resultCard` is **not** inside any method, it's a field of the enclosing class. Second: in the code I posted there is no `void[]` to be seen anywere, I don't know where you get that!